# my pyspark did not start on terminal,but with jupyter notebook

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, spark-shell

Not long ago,
when I input `pyspark` in my terminal.

the terminal will finally become...um...like this:

`some information`

`>>>`

but now it start with jupyter notebook automatically.

This phenomenon happened with `spark-3.0.0-preview2-bin-hadoop3.2`

I have used many version of spark.

Is above phenomenon due to my error in configuration or due to spark edition update?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON = jupyter does this environment variable exists ?

Comment: YES，how to make pyspark start with`>>>`,sorry for such not accurate description.

Comment: just unset this system variable, i bet you have set this system somewhere in your bash or zsh file thats way.

you can delete this line in your bash file or just UNSET PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON every time before you start spark